# How do I get VSCode to load code file from disk

Tags: visual-studio-code

I opened a Jupyter notebook from my local disk in VSCode.  I made some changes and then closed the file without saving changes.  But when I open the file again VSCode shows it with the changes I made and didn't save, and I can't figure out how to get VSCode to give me the version that's on my disk.

(To confirm that the disk version and VSCode version are different, I made a copy of the disk version and opened that, and VSCode shows the original version as expected.  This all occurs regardless of whether I close and reopen VSCode.)

Comment: Close the file (not VS Code), say "no" when it goes "save changes?" and then reopen it?